# Querying Active Directory from MVC result in: Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131014)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, active-directory

I have an issue using c# on .Net 4 in a MVC web application, where when I query Active Directory, I *frequently* get an error: ***Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131014).***

The strange thing is, that it will work flawlessly for a time, and then it will just start happening, and then just disappear again.

I have made a few modifications to the function to get it to work , but they all seem to fail. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a better way to do it.

Here is my current function, that will accept a loginId, and a PrincipalContext. The loginId can either be the user DisplayName *i.e "John Smith"*, or *DOMAINNAME\josmi*. The default is to use the first 2 letters of their firstname, and then the first 3 letters of their surname. There is a check in there if this is not the case. This part if fine.

```
public List<ADGroup> GetMemberGroups(string loginId, PrincipalContext principalContext, int tries = 0)
{
    var result = new List<ADGroup>();

    try
    {
        var samAccountName = "";
        if (loginId.Contains(" "))
        {
            var fName = loginId.Split(Char.Parse(" "))[0].ToLower();
            var sName = loginId.Split(Char.Parse(" "))[1].ToLower();

            if (sName.Trim().Length == 2)
                samAccountName = string.Format("{0}{1}", fName.StartsWith(".") ? fName.Substring(0, 4) : fName.Substring(0, 3), sName.Substring(0, 2));
            else
                samAccountName = string.Format("{0}{1}", fName.StartsWith(".") ? fName.Substring(0, 3) : fName.Substring(0, 2), sName.Substring(0, 3));
        }
        else
            samAccountName = loginId.Substring(loginId.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);

        var authPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName);

        if (authPrincipal == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("authPrincipal is null for loginId - {0}", loginId));

        var firstLevelGroups = authPrincipal.GetGroups();

        AddGroups(firstLevelGroups, ref result);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (tries > 5)
            throw;

        tries += 1;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        GetMemberGroups(loginId, principalContext, tries);
    }

    return result;
}

    private void AddGroups(PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> principal, ref List<ADGroup> returnList)
    {
        foreach (var item in principal)
        {
            if (item.GetGroups().Count() > 0)
                AddGroups(item.GetGroups(), ref returnList);

            returnList.Add(new ADGroup(item.SamAccountName, item.Sid.Value));
        }
    }
```

This function is called like this:

```
MembershipGroups = ad.GetMemberGroups(user.SamAccountName, new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain));
```

The the error that I *SOMETIMES* get is:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException:
>   Attempted to access an unloaded
>   appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131014)    at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.InternalGetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32
>   hr, IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis)    at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32
>   hr, IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UnsafeNativeMethods.IADsPathname.Retrieve(Int32
>   lnFormatType)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.LoadDomainInfo()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.get_UserSuppliedServerName()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.BuildPathFromDN(String
>   dn)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNextPrimaryGroupDN()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()

Comment: I'm having the same problem with random `AppDomainUnloadedException`s when calling into `S.DS.AM` and can't find a solution. Here's hoping that attaching a bounty will get some eyeballs on this...

Comment: One trick that at least worked for me is when you initialize the PrincipalContext pass the domain name in constructor.  PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"AD");

Comment: @Reza's comment seems to have done the trick for me. I was having the same error and passing in the domain seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

looking though reflector at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement the internal class "UnsafeNativeMethods" is implemented in native code, so UserSuppliedServerName one level up is all I can go on without looking at the CLR VM, (frankly im not sure even how to do that) Seems that a node is failing to return its primary group, so perhaps consider other implementations, after a bit of googling ive come across these that may help

- [Active Directory and nested groups](http://www.funkycoding.com/?p=345) *this one may be promising* heres the code sample..

  ```
      public IList<string> FindUserGroupsLdap(string username)
  { 
      // setup credentials and connection  
      var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");  
      var ldapidentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("server", 389, true, false); 
      var ldapConn = new LdapConnection(ldapidentifier, credentials); 
      // retrieving the rootDomainNamingContext, this will make sure we query the absolute root   
      var getRootRequest = new SearchRequest(string.Empty, "objectClass=*", SearchScope.Base, "rootDomainNamingContext");  
      var rootResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConn.SendRequest(getRootRequest);   
      var rootContext = rootResponse.Entries[0].Attributes["rootDomainNamingContext"][0].ToString();  
      // retrieve the user 
      string ldapFilter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", username); 
      var getUserRequest = new SearchRequest(rootContext, ldapFilter, SearchScope.Subtree, null);  
      var userResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConn.SendRequest(getUserRequest);     
      // send a new request to retrieve the tokenGroups attribute, we can not do this with our previous request since 
      // tokenGroups needs SearchScope.Base (dont know why...)  
      var tokenRequest = new SearchRequest(userResponse.Entries[0].DistinguishedName, "(&(objectCategory=person))", SearchScope.Base, "tokenGroups");  
      var tokenResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConn.SendRequest(tokenRequest);  
      var tokengroups = tokenResponse.Entries[0].Attributes["tokenGroups"].GetValues(typeof(byte[])); 
      // build query string this query will then look like (|(objectSid=sid)(objectSid=sid2)(objectSid=sid3))  
      // we need to convert the given bytes to a hexadecimal representation because thats the way they   
      // sit in ActiveDirectory  
      var sb = new StringBuilder();  
      sb.Append("(|");   
      for (int i = 0; i < tokengroups.Length; i++)  
      {  
          var arr = (byte[])tokengroups[i];    
          sb.AppendFormat("(objectSid={0})", BuildHexString(arr));   
      }   
      sb.Append(")");    
      // send the request with our build query. This will retrieve all groups with the given objectSid
      var groupsRequest = new SearchRequest(rootContext, sb.ToString(), SearchScope.Subtree, "sAMAccountName"); 
      var groupsResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConn.SendRequest(groupsRequest); 
      // loop trough and get the sAMAccountName (normal, readable name)   
      var userMemberOfGroups = new List<string>();    
      foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in groupsResponse.Entries)    
      userMemberOfGroups.Add(entry.Attributes["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString());  
      return userMemberOfGroups;
  } 

  private string BuildHexString(byte[] bytes)
  {  
      var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
      for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) 
      sb.AppendFormat("\\{0}", bytes[i].ToString("X2")); 
      return sb.ToString();
  }
  ```

These are more for info purposes

- [How to use the PrimaryGroupID attribute to find the primary group for a user](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297951)
- [Determining User Group Membership in Active Directory and ADAM](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Determining_User_Group_Membership_in_Active_Directory_and_ADAM)

Comment: I will try this method out today, and hopefully post my findings in a few hours. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: @Ryk - did you ever confirm (after the tests you mentioned in your last comment) this code snipped to be a reliable fix?

Comment: @wakurth - Yes, still using it today reliably. However I have not since then checked to see whether there could be better solutions/fixes. It works, so I kinda leave it alone

Comment: @almog.ori does this problem exist for Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: Probably not seeing as Microsoft issued an os patch for earlier releases as the other answers state but it's an untested theory

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how `PrincipalContext` is being passed in, here, but one thing I noticed in my own code and research when I had this error, I had:

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext , strUserName);
```

Where `strUserName` was some user, i.e. `DOMAIN\johndoe`

I was calling that code (which was in a separate function) and returning the `UserPrincipal` object as `up` and passing it to:

```
using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = up.GetGroups())
{
    // do something with result, here
}
```

`result` wouldn't be null, but after I checked for that condition, I checked if `result.Count() > 0`, and that's when it would fail (sometimes - though I could re-create the conditions when it would happen by clicking on a particular tab in my app that called this code - even though the same code was called onload of my app and had no issues).  The `Message` property in `result` was `Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131014)`.

I found in [a similar post](https://forums.asp.net/t/1944520.aspx?Error%20Attempted%20to%20access%20an%20unloaded%20appdomain%20Exception%20from%20HRESULT%200x80131014%20) to this one that all I had to do was specify the domain in my `PrincipalContext`.  Since I could not hard code mine in, as we move our code between Dev, Test, and Production environments where they have different domains for each of these, I was able to specify it as `Environment.UserDomainName`:

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
```

This got rid of the error, for me.

Comment: Worked for me too, Server 2012

Comment: I had this: `_context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);`
Changed for this: 
`_context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);`

And it worked.

Comment: @Sworgkh Yeah, yours is a quicker way of saying the same as I was saying in my long-winded explanation! :)

Answer (score 4):

This issue is the same as [Determine if user is in AD group for .NET 4.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168361/determine-if-user-is-in-ad-group-for-net-4-0-application/13594279#13594279)

It appears to be a bug in ADSI that was resolved with a hotfix. Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 don't include the fix, so it will need to be manually deployed on your development machines and server environments.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2683913

Comment: This hotfix worked for me.  Judging from the description, I'd say that the accepted answer may just be a workaround by not using the faulty AccountManagement namespace.  However, the API is so much cleaner that I think this should be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could put in some logging to narrow down the problem.  That `Thread.Sleep` does not look like something one would want in a web application :)

If you are getting exceptions maybe you could handle them differently.

I reckon your AppDomain is being recycled while AD is doing its voodoo.  Adding logging to the `Application_End` could also provide some clues.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I will give that a go. I 100% agree with you on the Thread.Sleep thing, but I only added that after a few forums suggested that it worked. Well, it did not! :(

Comment: Can't find anything in logging to assist me there, sorry

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public List<ADGroup> GetMemberGroups(string loginId, PrincipalContext principalContext, int tries = 0)
{

var result = new List<ADGroup>();
bool Done = false;

try
{
    var samAccountName = "";
    if (loginId.Contains(" "))
    {
        var fName = loginId.Split(Char.Parse(" "))[0].ToLower();
        var sName = loginId.Split(Char.Parse(" "))[1].ToLower();

        if (sName.Trim().Length == 2)
            samAccountName = string.Format("{0}{1}", fName.StartsWith(".") ? fName.Substring(0, 4) : fName.Substring(0, 3), sName.Substring(0, 2));
        else
            samAccountName = string.Format("{0}{1}", fName.StartsWith(".") ? fName.Substring(0, 3) : fName.Substring(0, 2), sName.Substring(0, 3));
    }
    else
        samAccountName = loginId.Substring(loginId.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);

    var authPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName);

    if (authPrincipal == null)
        throw new Exception(string.Format("authPrincipal is null for loginId - {0}", loginId));

    var firstLevelGroups = authPrincipal.GetGroups();

    AddGroups(firstLevelGroups, ref result);

    Done = true;
}
catch
{
    if (tries > 5)
        throw;

    tries += 1;
}

if ( ( !Done) && (tries < 6) )
     {
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     result = GetMemberGroups(loginId, principalContext, tries);
     }

return result;
}

private void AddGroups(PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> principal, ref List<ADGroup> returnList)
{
    if ( principal == null )
         return;
    foreach (var item in principal)
    {
        if (item.GetGroups().Count() > 0)
            AddGroups(item.GetGroups(), ref returnList);

        returnList.Add(new ADGroup(item.SamAccountName, item.Sid.Value));
    }
}
```

When an exception happens you called the function again from the catch-block (depending on the value of tries) but *discarded its return value - so even if the second/third... call worked you returned an empty result to the original caller*.
I changed that so the result won't be discarded anymore...

In the second function you never checked the principal param for null before starting the foreach... I changed that too...

And I removed the recursion from within the catch block catch (although I am really not sure whether this change has any real effect).

Comment: Thank you for your effort here Yahia, you are 100% correct in the code you provided, however, it still would fail from time to time. The solution which almog.ori provided works 100%. And I think his explanation is spot on. Once again, thank you.