# How to assign DL mail address to Outlook.AddressEntry object to GetExchangeDistributionListMembers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a requirement in my web application to all show particular page to people who are member of particular DL.

kindly help me on the below code i'm not able to assign dl mail addesser.

```
private void GetDistributionListMembers()
        {            
            string test = "test@mail.com";            

                Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry == ???


                    Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList exchDL =  addrEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList();
                    Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries =  exchDL.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
                    if (addrEntries != null)
                        foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry exchDLMember
                            in addrEntries)
                        {
                            //Debug.WriteLine(exchDLMember.Name);
                        }                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call Namespace.ResolveName, (returns Recipient object), call Recipient.Resolve, use Recipient.AddressEntry property.

Comment: Thanks i have used this technique for this requirement... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168361/determine-if-user-is-in-ad-group-for-net-4-0-application